# I have a yarn build --watch command not working in my Ruby on Rails project, want to know why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, project, hadoop-yarn

when I run the command yarn build --watch I get this following error:

➜  Le-Wagon-Career-Week-Challenge git:(mapbox-2) ✗ yarn build --watch
yarn run v1.22.19
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/yentung/code/Cheningit/Le-Wagon-Career-Week-Challenge"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

going into the link doesn't really help me, anyone have suggestions? thanks.

I did a yarn install to ensure that everything is up to date, as well as yarn init (which successfully saved package.json)